# How to append custom string to error output and redirect it to a file

Tags: bash

**Given**:

An `ffprobe` command that detects duration of an `mp4` video files on a remote host.

**Expected**:

Output of `ffprobe` is prefixed with custom string and redirected to a text file.

**Problem**:

Sometimes due to network error, `ffprobe` fails with some error message. I would like to capture that error, prefix it with a custom string and send it to a text file.

**Example**:

This command appends "ABC=55" to `out.txt` where 55 is the discovered duration:

> ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 https://example.com/video.mp4' | awk '{print "ABC="$1}' 2>&1 >> out.txt

However, if that same command encounters a network error, instead of writing "ABC=Error message here", it writes noting to text file and shows that message in console.

**Question**

How do I tweak this part to capture execution errors, prefix them with "ABC=" and send to `out.txt`?

> | awk '{print "ABC="$1}' 2>&1 >> out.txt

Thank you.

**EDIT**

This solved the problem:

> 2>&1 | awk '{print "ABC="$0}'

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
ffprobe cmd... 2>&1|awk '{print "ABC="$1}' >output.txt
```

Comment: "2>&1 | awk '{print "ABC="$0}'" fixed it. Had to use $0

Comment: @temuri I took the `$1` just from your original codes, I have no idea which part do you really need (whole line vs the 1st field). However, it is irrelevant. The point here is, which stderr you should redirect.